# How do I position widgets using grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a restaurant menu using tkinter. I want the menu items listed in a label widget below the course buttons but the label and one of the buttons share a column which throw the spacing of the whole thing out of whack.

This is my program so far:

```
#Setup - TKinter
import tkinter as tk
w = tk.Tk()
w.title("Interactive Restaurant Menu")
w.geometry("640x640")
w.resizable(False,False)
w['bg'] = 'black'

#Setup - SQL
import mysql.connector as mc
con = mc.connect(user = 'root',host = 'localhost', password = 'Cars!234',database = 'Zayan')
cur = con.cursor()

#Setup - Widgets
head = tk.Label(text = "Menu",font = ("Garamond",40),bg = 'black')
head.grid(column = 0,row = 0,columnspan = 4, sticky = 'N', pady = 10)

app = tk.Button(text="Entrees",width = 12,height = 2)
main = tk.Button(text="Mains",width = 12,height = 2,)
des = tk.Button(text="Desserts",width = 12,height = 2)
deal = tk.Button(text="Deals",width = 12,height = 2)

app.grid(column = 0, row = 1,padx = 8)
main.grid(column = 1, row = 1,padx = 8)
des.grid(column = 2, row = 1,padx = 8)
deal.grid(column = 3, row = 1,padx = 8)
w.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1)

list = tk.Label(text = '')
list.grid(column = 0,row = 2)

#Setup - Python
descEntree = {
    1:"Flour tortilla triangles filled with shredded cheddar, monterey jack, chicken, salsa and pico de gallo"
}
descMain = {}
descDessert = {}

def getItem(ID, course):
    currentItem = ''
    table_name = "Menu" + course
    query = "SELECT Item FROM {} WHERE ID = %s".format(table_name)
    cur.execute(query, (ID,))
    result = cur.fetchone()
    currentItem = result[0]
    return currentItem

def printItems(course):
    cur.execute("select max(ID) from {}".format("Menu" + course))
    n = cur.fetchone()
    for i in range(1,n[0] + 1):
        list.config(text = getItem(i,'Entree') + '\n' + descEntree[1])

printItems('Entree')

w.mainloop()
```

This is what the window looks like:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ImzN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the code in line 30 to this:

```
list.grid(column = 0, row = 2, columnspan = 4)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).